# Access Forms prevent mouse from selecting values from dropdown, force keyb input

Tags: forms, ms-access, mouse, dropdownbox

I have a data entry form. Its properly tab indexed etc. and there are three dropdown menus which automatically unfurl with the on enter event.

No matter how much advice i give to users about using the tab key and keboard and checking what they just input. 
they still insist on using the mouse to select values from the dropdown menus
the problem is that in their haste they often make mistakes as a result of using the mouse.

I would like to be able to force users to input into these fields using the keyboard.

the drop down is neccessary for users see the appropriate values for the field because the values will vary based on previous selections.

I have already tried experimenting with onclick events but to no avail. 
Is there a way I can do this?

i am using access 2007 many of the users have access 2003.

Comment: You will end up with a riot on your hands, I reckon. Why would someone want to scroll the arrow down through a dozen items? Why not add "are you sure" at the end if you want to slow them down? I will tell you now that it will not help much. Users enter the wrong data, that is what users are for. When accuracy is essential, you must use a double entry system. If accuracy is less important, you need to use data validation and / or proofing.

Comment: LOL Users enter the wrong data, that is what users are for. like it!!. have tried are you sure Y/N they just hit Y every time,i agree why would someone want to point scroll and click when they can use the tab key and numpad which is so much easier..  Riot or no I need to force the Values to be input from the keyboard because its taking too much time to check everything and correct it

Comment: What makes you think the data entry errors are strictly due to their use of the mouse?  And why are you so sure the error rate will drop if they are restricted to using the keyboard only?  Before I completely shattered the expected user experience, I would try something less jarring.  An easy thing to try that can make a big difference is increasing the number of items shown in the dropdown.   Depending on how many options are in the dropdown, setting the List Rows property to something like 20 or 25 could result in elimination of the scroll bar on the dropdown, thus improving usability.

Comment: We are are only talking about between 3 to 9 values in the list... they are codes like 101, 102, 103, etc  and also codes like F, V, S, T  Users know what the codes represent and they are simple to input. I have observed users working with the form and it is a combination of the mouse and haste which is producing erors. The user experience has been greatly improved of late. reducing considerable time spent on the form. using validation rules and alike

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I would take one of two different approaches.

If your users are *really* comfortable with the codes AND know which ones they should use based on their previous selections, then just **use text boxes instead of combo boxes**.  You can still put some validation code in either the Form_BeforeUpdate event or the individual control's _BeforeUpdate event.

If the users are not that comfortable, then I would suggest you **have the first field in the combo boxes be the description of the code, not the code itself**.  So instead of choosing from 101, 102, 103 they are instead choosing from "Small", "Medium", "Large" or whatever those codes actually apply to.  If you still wanted to display the codes themselves, you could do that with a separate disabled text box.

---

Now to answer your actual question.  For the record, I highly recommend *against* using this approach.  The simplest way I can thing of to prevent your users from using the mouse to select the combo box, would be to add a Transparent button covering the combo box.

To do this, draw a regular command button over the combo.  Set Transparent = Yes, Visible = Yes, Enabled = Yes, Tab Stop = No.

When users click on the combo now, they will actually be clicking on the Transparent button and nothing will happen.  The ONLY way they will be able to get into the control is by tabbing from a neighboring control or using a hotkey (via '&' in attached label).

Once they enter the control via Tab and your code forces a dropdown, they will still be able to choose an option using the mouse.  But by forcing them to use the keyboard initially, it will make it much more likely that they just stick with the keyboard.

Again--I can't stress this enough--I think this is a terrible, horrible, no-good idea.  Please don't use this approach.  But you asked a technical question and this site is all about giving technical answers, so there you go...

Comment: Thanks again, i have experimented with these approaches, i also tried things like DoCmd.CancelEvent on the mousedown event for the control.. On the one hand i see that the developer wants to make the experience 'NICE' for the user, but there is also a balance that has to be struck with effectiveness and accuracy especially if inaccuracy is going to cost money, I perhaps should have mentioned that the data is being entered onto a continuous subform,,  the invisible box is a neat trick, but i still havn't got a great solution yet, but select description and binding the values looks the way to go